# Facing error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm facing error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at for (int i= 2; i<datasetData.get((datasetData.size()-1)).length; i++) i'm not able to understand why i'm getting this error.

PFB code block:

```
private CategoryDataset createDataset(String path){
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    List<String[]> datasetData = FileOperations.getInstance().readCSV(path);
    for (int i= 2; i<datasetData.get((datasetData.size()-1)).length; i++) {
        dataset.setValue(Integer.parseInt(datasetData.get((datasetData.size()-1))[i]), "Requests", datasetData.get(0)[i]);          
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

I'm trying to run the code from https://github.com/dmarcas/locustapitest

PFB complete ERROR logs:

> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
> ------------------------------------------------------- Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /home/sonali/locustapitest &&
> /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_251/jre/bin/java -jar
> /home/sonali/locustapitest/target/surefire/surefirebooter4278625619835674105.jar
> /home/sonali/locustapitest/target/surefire/surefire5330964498682944855tmp
> /home/sonali/locustapitest/target/surefire/surefire_0265241717012809196tmp
> Running runner.TestRunner Jul 06, 2020 6:53:47 PM
> helpers.FileOperations readCSV SEVERE: Something went wrong reading
> the CSV Report file Jul 06, 2020 6:53:47 PM
> performance.LocustOperations checkMaxResponseTime SEVERE: Something
> went wrong cheking the MaxResponseTime Jul 06, 2020 6:53:47 PM
> helpers.FileOperations readCSV SEVERE: Something went wrong reading
> the CSV Report file Jul 06, 2020 6:54:57 PM helpers.FileOperations
> readCSV SEVERE: Something went wrong reading the CSV Report file Jul
> 06, 2020 6:54:57 PM performance.LocustOperations checkMaxResponseTime
> SEVERE: Something went wrong cheking the MaxResponseTime Jul 06, 2020
> 6:54:57 PM helpers.FileOperations readCSV SEVERE: Something went wrong
> reading the CSV Report file
>
> Failed scenarios: test.feature:14 # Scenario Outline: Request a forced
> answer test.feature:15 # Scenario Outline: Request a forced answer
>
> 2 Scenarios (2 failed) 4 Steps (4 passed) 2m20.234s
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
> at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
> at graph.LocustBarChart.createDataset(LocustBarChart.java:58)
> at graph.LocustBarChart.createChart(LocustBarChart.java:44)
> at stepsdefinition.Hooks.AfterSteps(Hooks.java:28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was able to solve the following issues by doing some changes:**

**Issue 1:** The folder target/csvlocustsresults was not getting created automatically once mvn clean install is done so I fixed that by adding maven-antrun-plugin in pom.xml. Also as I have locust 0.13.5 running on python version 3.5 and in that the distributed and requests CSV are getting created with another name hence changed both in src/main/resources/configs/config.properties

```
requestsReportLocation=target/csvlocustsresults/performanceResults_stats.csv
distributionReportLocation=target/csvlocustsresults/performanceResults_stats_history.csv
```

**Issue 2:** I was facing NumberFormatException : fixed that by changing the parsing from Integer to Float in method createDataset() and checkMaxResponseTime()

**Issue 3:** No wait time was mentioned in the dummy python file. Added wait_time = between(5, 9) under class Dummy(Locust)

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it seems that `datasetData` is empty. It was created on this line:

```
List<String[]> datasetData = FileOperations.getInstance().readCSV(path);
```

So "something" goes wrong when reading the file. For example, maybe the path is wrong. Maybe the file is in the wrong place. Maybe the file is empty.

Comment: I tried to debug and found out that is it searching for the file "/locustapitest/target/csvlocustsresults/performanceResults_distribution.csv"    which I guess supposed to be created automatically once I have maven install the project. Is there anything I can do in this?

Comment: That path doesn't seem right, it should be either relative (no / in the beginning) or it should start with your home directory where you've downloaded this package, /home/sonali

Comment: I have corrected that but even with that, it is throwing the same error.